# SQL SERVER - select distinct random number of rows

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

I have the below query that selects 100 random rows.  However I also need to select the distinct name.  I have tried using `SELECT DISTINCT u.name` and also using `GROUP BY u.name` but cannot get anything to work.

```
SELECT TOP (100) c.id, u.id u.name, b.sector, u.default
FROM cads AS c 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.cad = u.id 
INNER JOIN business AS b ON u.id = b.cad
WHERE (c.[public] = 'True') AND (c.valid = 'True') 
        AND (u.default = '$curr') 
        AND (c.expires IS NULL OR c.expires >= GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need 1 result with 100 random values but in a distinct clause?

Comment: I need 100 results that are distinct and random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
SELECT TOP (100) min(c.id), u.id, u.name, min(b.sector), min(u.default)
FROM cads AS c 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.cad = u.id 
INNER JOIN business AS b ON u.id = b.cad
WHERE (c.[public] = 'True') AND (c.valid = 'True') 
        AND (u.default = '$curr') 
        AND (c.expires IS NULL OR c.expires >= GETDATE())
GROUP BY u.id, u.name 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via cunning use of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;With Arbitrary AS (
SELECT c.id, u.id u.name, b.sector, u.default,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.name ORDER BY newid()) as rn
FROM cads AS c 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.cad = u.id 
INNER JOIN business AS b ON u.id = b.cad
WHERE (c.[public] = 'True') AND (c.valid = 'True') 
        AND (u.default = '$curr') 
        AND (c.expires IS NULL OR c.expires >= GETDATE()) 
)
select top 100 * from Arbitrary ORDER BY newid()
```

(You do need both `ORDER BY` clauses because there's no guarantee that the inner one in the CTE will actually affect the order of rows being considered by the `TOP` operator)

Comment: The initial `;` is required unless the `With` is the first keyword in a batch. What error message are you getting?